# How to manipulate named tuples

Tags: julia

I like the idea of
[`NamedTuple`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#Named-Tuple-Types-1)
a lot, as a middle ground between `Tuple` and full, user-defined composite types.

I know how to build a named tuple and access one of its fields

```
julia> nt = (a=1, b=2.0)
(a = 1, b = 2.0)

julia> nt.a
1
```

however, I don't know much more and don't even know whether it is possible to do more than that. I'm thinking about a lot of ways we can manipulate plain tuples (usually involving splatting), and wonder if some of those apply to named tuples as well. For example, how to:

- dynamically build a `NamedTuple` from lists of fields and values
- grow a `NamedTuple` , i.e add new field-value pairs to it
- "update" (in an immutable sense) a field in an existing named tuple

Answer (score 15):

The [`NamedTupleTools`](https://github.com/JeffreySarnoff/NamedTupleTools.jl)
package contains a lot of tools aiming at making the use of `NamedTuples` more
straightforward. But here are a few elementary operations that can be performed
on them "manually":

**Creation**

```
       # regular syntax
julia> nt = (a=1, b=2.)
(a = 1, b = 2.0)

       # empty named tuple (useful as a seed that will later grow)
julia> NamedTuple()
NamedTuple()

       # only one entry => don't forget the comma
julia> (a=1,)
(a = 1,)
```

**Growth and "modification"**

It is possible to
[`merge`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.merge) two
named tuples to create a new one:

```
julia> merge(nt, (c=3, d=4.))
(a = 1, b = 2.0, c = 3, d = 4.0)
```

...or to re-use an existing `NamedTuple` by splatting it in the creation of a
new one:

```
julia> (; nt..., c=3, d=4.)
(a = 1, b = 2.0, c = 3, d = 4.0)
```

When the same field name appears multiple times, the last occurrence is
kept. This allows for a form of "copy with modification":

```
julia> nt
(a = 1, b = 2.0)

julia> merge(nt, (b=3,))
(a = 1, b = 3)

julia> (; nt..., b=3)
(a = 1, b = 3)
```

**Dynamic manipulations**

Using `field=>value` pairs in the various techniques presented above allows for
more dynamic manipulations:

```
julia> field = :c;

julia> merge(nt, [field=>1])
(a = 1, b = 2.0, c = 1)

julia> (; nt..., field=>1)
(a = 1, b = 2.0, c = 1)
```

The same technique can be used to build `NamedTuples` from existing dynamic data structures

```
julia> dic = Dict(:a=>1, :b=>2);
julia> (; dic...)
(a = 1, b = 2)

julia> arr = [:a=>1, :b=>2];
julia> (; arr...)
(a = 1, b = 2)
```

**Iteration**

Iterating on a `NamedTuple` iterates on its values:

```
julia> for val in nt
           println(val)
       end
1
2.0
```

Like all key->value structures, the
[`keys`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.keys) function
can be used to iterate over the fields:

```
julia> for field in keys(nt)
           val = nt[field]
           println("$field => $val")
       end
a => 1
b => 2.0
```

Comment: Nice answer. Note that if you want to `merge` a single key,value pair, you would add a comma: `merge(nt, (c=3,))`